# highcharts render bubbles series

Tags: javascript, highcharts, bubble-chart, highcharts-boost

My goal is to render large amount of series in **HighCharts** bubbles.

If I try to use **boost** module for this, there are some problems with my video driver.

I think, that boost module is trying to render each series data with GPU, but this is not working for the large amount of series.

For example:

```
// Prepare the data
var data = [],
    n = 200,
    i;
var seriesArray = []
for(j=0; j<n; j+=1) {

  for (i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
      data.push([
          Math.pow(Math.random(), 2) * 100,
          Math.pow(Math.random(), 2) * 100,
          Math.pow(Math.random(), 2) * 100
      ]);
  }
  var serie={
        type: 'bubble',
        boostBlending: 'alpha',
        color: 'rgb(152, 0, 67)',
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        data: data,
        minSize: 1,
        maxSize: 10,
        tooltip: {
            followPointer: false,
            pointFormat: '[{point.x:.1f}, {point.y:.1f}]'
        }
    };
  seriesArray.push(serie);
}


if (!Highcharts.Series.prototype.renderCanvas) {
    throw 'Module not loaded';
}

console.time('bubble');
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },

    xAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
    },

    yAxis: {
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Bubble chart with ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(data.length, 0, ' ') + ' points'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    boost: {
        useGPUTranslations: true,
        usePreallocated: true
    },

    series: seriesArray

});
console.timeEnd('bubble');
```

Comment: I suppose that you've forgotten to clear the `data` array while creating points for every series. It causes that every series has the same points in number of 40 000 (200 * 200). It's a huge amount of data and Highcharts may have problems rendering it. Adding `data = [];` before every iteration of `j` produces (probably) the desired chart: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vwqrf2n9/

Comment: thats work, thanks